# Laravel elixir angular and vue

Tags: angularjs, laravel, gulp, vue.js

guys!
My project based on Laravel framework. For main site using Angular, but for admin panel need vue.

I finded this package 
[Larave-Angular](https://www.laravel-angular.io/#/) with all configs. Package has this gulpfile

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-eslint');
require('./tasks/swPrecache.task.js');
require('./tasks/bower.task.js');
elixir.config.assetsPath = './';
elixir.config.css.folder = 'angular';
elixir.config.css.sass.folder = 'angular';
elixir.config.js.folder = 'angular';
 let assets = [
         'public/js/final.js',
         'public/css/final.css'
     ],enter code here
     scripts = [
         'public/js/vendor.js', 'public/js/app.js'
     ],
     styles = [
         './public/css/vendor.css', './public/css/app.css'
     ],
     karmaJsDir = [
         'public/js/vendor.js',
         'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
         'node_modules/ng-describe/dist/ng-describe.js',
         'public/js/app.js',
         'tests/angular/**/*.spec.js'
     ];
elixir(mix => {
    mix.bower()
       .copy('angular/app/**/*.html', 'public/views/app/')
       .copy('angular/dialogs/**/*.html', 'public/views/dialogs/')
       .webpack('index.main.js', 'public/js/app.js')
       .sass(['**/*.scss', 'critical.scss'], 'public/css')
       .sass('critical.scss', 'public/css/critical.css')
       .styles(styles, 'public/css/final.css')
       .eslint('angular/**/*.js')
       .combine(scripts, 'public/js/final.js')
       .version(assets)
       .swPrecache();
});
```

And I have the webpack.config file

```
module.exports = {
    // configuration
    entry: "./angular/index.main.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['ng-annotate','babel?presets[]=es2015'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }]
    }
};
```

When I try compiled vue files from assets/js, I gived with angular but not with vue. Something with global config?

**Or how can I using gulp separately for angular and for vue ?**

Comment: If angular's in `.js` and vue's in `.vue`, webpack is already able to distinguish them by extension and then apply different loader, you just need to merge the above gulp tasks with the default laravel-vue ones, so `gulp` and `gulp watch` build both angular and vue files.